# Can I install elementary on a Lenovo Tab 2 A10-70?

Tags: release-freya, lenovo

I would like to know if I can install elementary on my tablet.

Answer (score 2):

As your tablet uses an ARM processor instead of a 32 or 64 bit processor as is typical on laptops and desktops, elementary OS is not available for it at this time.